# Количество связанных записей в БД

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имею sql запрос вида:

```
SELECT g.id, g.user_id, g.name, count(ud.device_id) as c
FROM public.groups g inner join public.user_devices ud on g.id = ud.group_id
group by g.id
having g.id in (1, 2)
```

Запрос берет группы указанные группы и выводит нужный поля из таблицы и количество связанных с это группой записей в другой таблице.
Если связанные записи есть, то запрос выводит строку с группой и выводит количество связанных данных, но если данных нет совсем запрос вообще не выводит данных о группе.
Можно ли сделать запрос, чтобы он не не выводит группу без связей, а вместо этого писал 0?

Comment: используйте `left join` вместо `inner join`

Comment: `inner join` -> `left join`

Comment: Спасибо, глупая невнимательность((  Ответьте как ответ хоть кармы вам накину))

Comment: И переместите условие из HAVING во WHERE. Зачем заставлять сервер делать лишнюю работу?

Comment: да, согласен having лишнее

Comment: и поля группировки полностью опишите (user_id, name), или уберите из выборки

Comment: А не подскажите зачем и что прочитать, чтобы понять это?